# How to add a date to QStandardItem in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, char, timestamp

I have a time field in db(timestamp) e.g: 2014-12-23 11:55:54 
I want to show this table in my qtgui. I stored table fields inside of a vector. type of this "time" field is "const char*". I tried QString::fromUtf8 and ascii and local8bit.
 after that i only saw special characters in gui. How can i write my time field to gui correctly?

Btw I can't add code here because we have no internet connection, im using mobile here.

Comment: Are you sure the char* in the vector are still valid? what does printf/std::cout show? In C++, you should use std::string (or QString) to avoid such hassle.

Comment: Its valid, works fine. I teated it without using qt. shows correct date.

Comment: Show some code. You definitely messed up something. Adding to `QStandardItem` with a `QDateTime` created based on timestamp should work out of the box. Messing around with `const char*` or `QString::fromUtf8` is pointless (at least this indicates that you are doing something terribly wrong).

Comment: If it’s just plain text, then I don’t see why it shouldn’t work. Please show some code.

Comment: MyStruct contains: long long int, short int, char *, short int.  I use vector<mystruct> to store it. When i use QStandardItem *temp = new QStandardItem(QString::number(myStruct->at(1).id)); works fine.

Comment: MyStruct contains: long long int, short int, char *, short int.  I use vector<mystruct> to store it. When i use QStandardItem *temp = new QStandardItem(QString::number(myStruct->at(1).id)); works fine. However if i create qstring temp = qstring::fromutf8(mystruct->at(1).time); then use this qstring in qstandarditem. It shows some different characters. I tried to see this char * time in netbeans. It shows correctly.

Comment: I have changed char * to char time[19] and used Qstring str(time). thats worked. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

First add a variable current date and time

```
var today = new Date() // contains current date and time
```

Here you can arrange your settings like width height or you can describe your date format ..

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(), "yyMMdd")
    }
}
```

Last, just implement your function take current time and date. And Show them with textLabel

```
SystemTime::SystemTime(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    //get current date
    QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
    QString dateString = date.toString();
    ui.label->setText("Date: " + dateString);

    //get current time
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString timeString = time.toString();
    ui.label_2->setText("Time: " + timeString);

    //get current date and time
    QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QString dateTimeString = dateTime.toString();
    ui.label_3->setText("Date and Time: " + dateTimeString);
}
```

Comment: firstly thanks for long answer. however i already have dates in a vector(const char* format) my problem : i can't write it to a tableView in my gui. I used QStandardItem to save other fielda.